# Whats the best way to extend Anonymous User in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to make my User objects all have the same base behaviour and to do so I need to add a couple of methods / properties to Anonymous User.

I've already subclassed User to make richer user objects but I was wondering if anyone has done the same for Anonymous User?  And if there are any preferred ways of doing it!

Comment: I think the preferred way to extend the user model is not to subclass the `User` class but to create a separate `UserProfile` class, then add the desired fields to it and establish a ForeignKey relation to the `User` class.

Comment: Yeah I can see why that would be preferable, but AnonymousUser wouldn't have a UserProfile anyway as theres no where to FK to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your middleware suggestion got me thinking, and I now think the best idea is to overwrite the standard `AuthenticationMiddleware`. That class assigns a `LazyUser` object to the request, which is resolved to the correct user, when accessed, by calling `contrib.auth.get_user`. This is probably the right place to override things, so that it calls your customised `get_user` function which returns your subclassed `AnonymousUser`.

Comment: Works a treat cheers Daniel!  Heres a copy for prosperity: [custom auth backend](http://gist.github.com/397817)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler and more general (but less safe) solution would be to just replace `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser` with your own class:

```
class YourAnonymousUser(...):
    ...


import django.contrib.auth.models as django_auth_models
django_auth_models.AnonymousUser = YourAnonymousUser
```

As of 1.10.5, Django lazily imports the anonymous user class, so you won't run into issues with core Django. You also rarely interact with `AnonymousUser` directly, since you could just use `.is_anonymous()`, so  you should be fine as long as you know how your dependencies use `AnonymousUser`.

Comment: Your method works also for both WSGI requests and DRF requests, whilst the middleware method doesn't work for DRF.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a python package (or write your own) which will swap Django default AnonymousUser class with your own class. You can implement a middleware for this (I think it's the best place).

For example, you can use [django-custom-anonymous](https://github.com/bugov/django-custom-anonymous) to provide customization of AnonymousUser. Also you can find it on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-custom-anonymous).

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to think a middleware is probably the easiest solution that checks the `request.user` class and if is AnonymousUser then replaces it with a subclassed AnonymousUser that has the extra properties.

That sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined) which allows you to customise AnonymousUser through `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER` in settings likes this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': 'application.AnonymousUser',
}
```

Keep in mind that this user class will only be available from DRF [views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)

Answer (score -1):

You should subclass or create a model that has a one to one relationship with the [AnonymousUser class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser).

Comment: subclassing would be ideal, but is more about the practicalities of doing it, as the AnonymousUser class is imported directly in a number of places.